# Error in the creation of a class instance

Tags: python, class, error-handling

I have created the class `Animal`:

```py
class Animal:
    def __int__(self, height, weight):
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
```

Then I want to create the instance `animal_1` of class `Animal` like so:

```
animal_1 = Animal(height=120, weight=80)
```

And if I try to execute the code I get this error:

```
TypeError: Animal() takes no arguments
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: typo: __init__ .

Comment: @OriYarden Put backticks around code so the underscores won't be interpreted as markdown.

Comment: thank you @Barmar I haven't gotten a chance to learn the tools for commenting (I think commenting shouldn't have different hot-keys than answers, but ctrl  + k doesn't do its thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ori Yarden says in its comment the error is the name of the method `__int__()`.

Its correct name is `__init__` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) for official Python documentation).

So the code for a correct class definition and object instantiation is the following:

```
class Animal:
    # __int__ ---> __init__
    def __init__(self, height, weight):
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight

# create the instance animal_1
animal_1 = Animal(height=120, weight=80)

# print the value of the attributes pass to the class instantiation
print(f"height = {animal_1.height}, weight = {animal_1.weight}")
```

The output of the code execution is:

```
height = 120, weight = 80
```

Comment: We don't need this detailed an explanation for a typo; that's why we have close votes for such questions.